# How to get xfce4 desktop at startup without the bloat?

Tags: xfce, desktop-environments

I'm trying to keep things fairly minimal, but it's tough!

(Judging by what I read online, I have to pick for myself one of each of these:

1. a display manager
2. a greeter
3. a window manager
4. a desktop environment

Sheesh.

I don't know, maybe I don't need all of the above, but it's hard for me to tell what of this I really need, and what's bloat.)

Right now, the way I have it is that I get a text-only login interface, and, after I log in, I run

```
% exec startxfce4
```

This works OK, but I'd like to automate away that obligatory call to `exec startxfce4`.  I already have this very same command in `~/.xinitrc` (in fact, it's all I have in this file), but apparently it's not enough.  What do I need to do instead (or in addition)?

Also, the text-only interface is OK, except that the font is tiny (I have a high-rez screen), hard to read.  I wouldn't mind having a graphical login screen, but I have not been able to find one that I can install without installing a bazillion other packages alongside, many of them with names featuring the word "gnome", which I want to avoid.

Is there a *really minimal* graphic login that I can use to log into xfce4?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, you have already picked (4) - that's what XFCE is, a [desktop environment](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Desktop_environment), and thereby (3), the XFCE Window manager ([`xfwm`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/xfwm4)). XFCE doesn't include a display manager, but other desktop environments do (GNOME has GDM, LXDE as LXDM, KDE has KDM, Unity has LightDM), and most display managers come with a default greeter. So, in effect, once you pick a desktop environment, you usually have the other three choices made for you.

---

> after I log in, I run
>
> ```
> % exec startxfce4
> ```
>
> ... I already have this very same command in `~/.xinitrc`...

That's what [`startx`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/startx.1) does:

```
To  determine  the  client to run, startx first looks for a file called
.xinitrc in the user's home directory.  If that is not found,  it  uses
the  file  xinitrc  in  the  xinit  library directory.
```

So you need to run `startx` on login to a TTY. The Arch Wiki offers [a nice snippet](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Start_X_at_login) for doing this:

```
[[ -z $DISPLAY && $XDG_VTNR -eq 1 ]] && exec startx
```

You can add this to `.bashrc`, and when you login to TTY1 (see the check for `XDG_VTNR`), it will start the GUI.

---

As for display managers, [the Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Display_manager) lists quite a few, some of which are lightweight. You may have some luck with [SLiM](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/slim/), whose dependencies [are pretty minimal](http://packages.ubuntu.com/vivid/slim). It's also on the [list of recommended apps by XFCE](https://wiki.xfce.org/recommendedapps).